# Ways to say the "the desired data"

Tags: word-request

In many cases we want to say about the target object in an article but I feel lack of synonyms for these occasions

I just know

- Data of Interest
- The desired Data

What are the other ways?

In my case the user wants to extract specific or desired data from a web page, for example suppose you want just the question section not irrelevant bars on this page.

Comment: You could try expanding a little on what you're trying to accomplish by that term.  At this moment only "*crucial*" comes to mind...

Comment: @VictorBazarov in my case the user wants to extract specific or desired data from a web page, for example you want just the question section not irrelevent footer and header bars.

Comment: Edit your question please with this explanation.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I did

Comment: I have seen only "of interest" in journals ! ( about the mathematical goals and expressions )

Comment: Sounds like the "relevant data", as an antonym for "irrelevent" (sic)

Answer (score 1):

> In many cases we want to say about the target object

There's nothing wrong with exactly that:

- The *target* data.

All by itself, that could be considered ambiguous; does this mean to produce data within certain parameters, or acquire it?  *Desired* and pretty much anything else is going to suffer the same ambiguity unless it is strung together with other qualifiers in something very awkward.  Based on your comment (that it involves scraping HTML), the context makes it clear: we want to extract data within certain parameters (not stuff in the header, footer, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If the type of data to extract has been defined by a set of criteria, then it has been *specified*.

- the **specified** [type of] data